# Maven equivalent for .Net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maven

For me, the best feature in Maven is not having to keep 3rd party libraries at part of the source tree. Is there a tool for .Net/Visual Studio that does something like that?

Comment: I suggest reopening. This question is answerable, specific, not subjective, and involves programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest existing alternatives are [NuPack](http://nupack.codeplex.com/) or [NPanday](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/), but nothing exists that does all of what Maven does and which is also at its stability level and feature set. Most of the community consensus is converging around NuPack, though.

**Update:** The NuPack project is now called [**NuGet**](https://github.com/nuget/home) as of [November 5, 2010](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/282).

Comment: Actually Nuget does not really have an option for NOT checking in the downloaded libraries, as it does not integrate with any build tool. Gotta go with NPanday, then :-)